# Formula only if cell not empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to do a formula that will fill the cell value, but only once, when the cell is empty. Once filled I want the value to stay as is, even though cells that are part of the formula changed.

ie

```
C: =VLOOKUP(Cx,'A$1:B$3,2,FALSE)
```

Originaly

```
A       B      C
John    1      1
Bob     4      4
Jim     6      6
```

After Changing Jim's B value

```
Jim     10      6
```

So I want the VLOOKUP to fetch a value only if one isn't there already. I tried to do it with an IF, but I got a circular reference error:

```
=IF(C1= "", VLOOKUP(C1,'A$1:B$3,2,FALSE),C1)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be a macro instead of a formula?

Comment: I don't see a way without a macro.

Comment: Irrispective of the curcular refeerence, if `C1` is blank how can you look it up, unless you ment `B1`? Or are you going to look up a blank value?

Comment: Formulas are dynamic in the sense that, when one of the references change, so does the evaluated result of the formula. Unless you have calculation set to Manual but even that doesn't *really* solve your problem, it merely masks the fact that formulas are dynamic. An alternative to using macros would be to use some formula to return the result, and then copy/paste values to break the formula references.

Comment: GLH, you're correct. In fact I completely screwed up the example. There should have been 4 cols A and B as reference table C containing the Name to be matched to A, and D as the resulting value. So if D was empty I'd get the value form B and if already filled, I'd leave it alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is along the lines you want

- right-click your sheet tab
- `View Code`
- copy and paste in the code below
- press [alt](/questions/tagged/alt) & [f11](/questions/tagged/f11) to get back to Excel

If you enter say 12 in `B4` **and** `A4` is not blank then

1. If `C4` is empty, it will be sety equal to 12
2. if `C4` has a value, it is retained

**code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Columns("B:B"), Target)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each rng2 In rng1
If rng2.Offset(0, -1).Value <> vbNullString Then rng2.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng2.Value
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 nice one. im still not sure what the op wants though... I'll put mine in anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure of what you want but I think brettdj has the answer. Mine will change all empty cells in column C to a formula, to be modified to your situation, at the moment it just looks up the name and returns the column B value.

**Please I know** the `VLOOKUP()` is not required, but I wanted to show how to use it in this context.

```
Sub change_empty()

    Dim l As Long, r As Range
    l = Me.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    Set r = Me.Range("C1").Resize(l).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    r.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,C1:C2,2,FALSE)"

End Sub
```